# How to handle multiple-language site without database or backend code?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small site (8 or 10 pages) that needs to be translated into Spanish. I don't have access to a back end developer in order to use any sort of database or variables, and so I am going to try and finagle my way through this with just CSS/jQuery.

I know how to change the elements on a page from English to Spanish and vice versa.  My problem is that once the visitor clicks to a new page, how I can make sure that the next page displays in the proper language?  Is this even possible?

The pages are .aspx but I don't have access to the code behind and I'm relatively useless in .NET.  I wouldn't even take this on but its only a few pages with very little text.

Could someone help me get going in the right direction here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use cookie to save the chosen language.

I think that this will work:

```
function changeLang(lang) {
    var a = 0;
    Set_Cookie('lang',lang, 30, "/");
    location.reload(false);
}

function Set_Cookie( name, value, expires, path, domain, secure )
{
// set time, it's in milliseconds
var today = new Date();
today.setTime( today.getTime() );

if ( expires )
{
    expires = expires * 60 * 60 * 24;
}
var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );

document.cookie = name + "=" +escape( value ) +
( ( expires ) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" ) +
( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "" ) +
( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
( ( secure ) ? ";secure" : "" );
}
```

Comment: It's true, you can use the cookie....but if all you're working with is front-end technology, then you have to find some place to store all that content.  You --could-- put in 2 divs with content and do show/hide based on cookies, but then you're sending double the content --and double the data-- than you'd have to.  If you agree with this premise, then you're back to a translator or using backend technology to only send the desired content.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I agree with you completely, I was just trying to figure out how to handle it and thought the same thing, I will have one div for each language and simply show/hide as i need. But its not ideal that is for sure...  Unfortunately, for the time being, i dont have a back-end developer. I am desperate for our company to hire one, but they seem to be having trouble locating one, IMO they are looking in the wrong places...

Comment: Would it be possible to use a script that the one above to redirect to a sub directory?  www.mysite.com/sp/ for example?  I have never worked with cookies.

Answer (score 1):

How about Sunday Morning--it's Google Translate done with Jquery.  Simple, quick, and no DB required.

http://sundaymorning.jaysalvat.com/

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with css only:

```
<div class="text-1"></div>
```

in your css file:

```
.text-1:after {
  content: "Hello World"
}
```

now all you need is a css file for every language,

find demo here http://jsfiddle.net/CyfBF/1/

Comment: Hmm I will have to chew on this a bit. There isnt a lot of text on the site, but it might be a bit confusing incorporating it all into css.  And how about images with language and list elements?

Comment: i wouldn't do that under normal circumstances, but if you work in a very restricted environment it might be a useful hack